# For which server roles should the Timer Service be started?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, timer-service

Simple question but I don't have clarification on it.

I have the following server roles in my farm:

- 2 WFE
- 2 APP
- 1 Search

Should SPTimerV4 be started only on APP servers or on all servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint Timer Service is a crucial component for each server in the farm and should be running on every server.

Excerpt from a related and very informative [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/10/26/the-sharepoint-timer-service/):

> If the Timer Service or any of its instances on servers begins to
>   malfunction, it won't take long for problems to begin appearing across
>   the farm.